# Sumar Columnas de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola amigos buenas tardes
Necesito una ayuda, quiero sumar los importes totales, los importes no cancelados que son los que tienen "N" y los importes si cancelados que son los que tienen "S" y quiero ponerlo en cada TextBox.

Tengo este codigo que es el del Total:

```
double suma = 0;
(DataGridViewRow row in dgvClientes.Rows)
{
    suma += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Value);
}
txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(suma);
```

Solo me faltaria el de "S" y "N"

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Hola, deberias poner lo q has intentado

Comment: `double suma = 0;`
`(DataGridViewRow row in dgvClientes.Rows)`
`{`
`suma += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Value);`
`}`
`txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(suma);`

@Japv Eso es lo que intente pero solo me da la suma total, lo que necesitaria es como hacer para sumar solo los que tienen "S" y "N".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double sumaTotal = 0;
double SumaNoCancelados = 0;
double SumaCancelados = 0;
double Imporete = 0;

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgvClientes.Rows)
{
    Importe = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Value);
    sumaTotal += Importe;

    if(string)(row.Cells[5].Value == "S")
    {
       sumaCancelados += Importe;
    }
    else if(string)(row.Cells[5].Value == "N")
    {
       sumaNoCancelados += Importe;
    }
}

txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sumaTotal);
txtCancelados.Text = Convert.ToString(sumaCancelados);
txtNoCancelados.Text = Convert.ToString(sumaNoCancelados);
```

Bien igualmente recorro las filas del **DataGridView**, y voy sumando como ya haces el total de todos los importes, posteriormente pregunta si está cancelado, de estarlo pues sumo en la **variable sumaCancelados**, de no estarlo pues sumo en la **variable sumaNoCancelados**, posteriormente imprimo en los **TextBox** todas estas sumas.